# “Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements”

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, collections, hibernate-mapping

Good morning Stackoverflow,

I have the problem that it gives me the error:

> Failed to create sessionFactory
>   object.org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Illegal attempt to map a non
>   collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements:
>   nl.scalda.pasimo.model.employeemanagement.EducationTeam.coachGroups

Do you know why?

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity=CoachGroup.class)
@JoinColumn(name="id")
private TreeSet<CoachGroup> coachGroups = new TreeSet<>();
private SessionFactory factory;

private void initialiseFactory() {
    try {
        factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `TreeSet` and not `Set`?!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The Exception is straightforward and says : *Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements*, so the cause is obvious here and if we take a look at the [Hibernate **Collection mapping** documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html#collections-persistent) it clearly states that:

> As a requirement persistent collection-valued fields must be declared as an interface type (see Example 7.2, “Collection mapping using @OneToMany and @JoinColumn”). The actual interface might be `java.util.Set`, `java.util.Collection`, `java.util.List`, `java.util.Map`, `java.util.SortedSet`, `java.util.SortedMap`...

And you used [**TreeSet**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) which is an implementation **class** for both `Set<E>` and `SortedSet<E>` interfaces. So your actual mapping won't work with `TreeSet`, you should use a `Set<CoachGroup>` instead of a `TreeSet<CoachGroup>`:

```
private Set<CoachGroup> coachGroups = new HashSet<CoachGroup>();
```

Answer (score 6):

Another possible reasons for this exception to occur is using a non-collection object for
`@ManyToMany` and`@OneToMany` mappings Or using collection object for `@ManyToOne` and `@OneToOne` mappings. All examples below are incorrect.

**INCORRECT**

```
 @ManyToMany
 private User user;

 @ManyToOne
 private User user;

 @OneToOne
 private List<User> users;

 @ManyToOne
 private List<User> users;
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer... I had the same issue `@ManyToMany
 private User user`

Answer (score 4):

You should map to interfaces and not implementations. This:

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity=CoachGroup.class)
@JoinColumn(name="id")
private TreeSet<CoachGroup> coachGroups = new TreeSet<>();
```

Should be (also replaced the TreeSet because a HashSet is enough here):

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity=CoachGroup.class)
@JoinColumn(name="id")
private Set<CoachGroup> coachGroups = new HashSet<>();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't save your collection fields as Concrete classes.

Got this,

> As a requirement persistent collection-valued fields must be declared
> as an interface type (see Example 7.2, “Collection mapping using
> @OneToMany and @JoinColumn”). The actual interface might be
> java.util.Set, java.util.Collection, java.util.List, java.util.Map,
> java.util.SortedSet, java.util.SortedMap or anything you like
> ("anything you like" means you will have to write an implementation of
> org.hibernate.usertype.UserCollectionType).

From [Chapter 7. Collection Mapping](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html#collections-persistent).

You can use below code to save a sorted set:

> Please do read the comments too

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL) //Removed targetEntity, as you are already using generics.
@JoinColumn(name="team_id") // Use this name as to show the presence of foreign key of EducationTeam in CoachGroup.
@SortNatural // Make sure that your CoachGroup Entity has implemented Comparable<CoachGroup> interface which wii be used while sorting.
private SortedSet<CoachGroup> coachGroups = new TreeSet<>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to use a concrete implementation on the entities field declaration. You are allowed to use one of the following:

- java.util.List
- java.util.Set
- java.util.Collection

So in your case it would have to be:

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity=CoachGroup.class)
@JoinColumn(name="id")
private Set<CoachGroup> coachGroups = new TreeSet<>();
```