# illegal-attempt-to-map-a-non-collection-as-a-onetomany-manytomany-or-collectionofelements in Spring

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

I want to send a JSON as POST Request to insert into the database. Following is the JSON

```
{
    "url": "https://www.tec.com",
    "status":"Regular",
     "Student": 
     {
         "id": 1,
         "name": "John Doe",
         "age": 12      
    }
}
```

where I have the main class

**Data.java**

```
@ToString
@Setter
@Getter
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "data")
public class Data implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int id;
    private String url;
    private String status;

    @ElementCollection
    private Student student;
}
```

**Student.java**

```
@ToString
@Setter
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "Student")
public class Student implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int age;
}
```

Please tell me how to resolve this .So that the data should save in the database when I send the JSON on the above-specified format.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44258541/illegal-attempt-to-map-a-non-collection-as-a-onetomany-manytomany-or-collec/44259547

Comment: @trim24 i have also read this article as you have shared. But it doesn't make any sense to me. Please answer as per my scenario.

Comment: It is probably the same scenario, Can you trying  replacing with `Set<Student>` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting this error message because you placed the `@ElementCollection` annotation on `student`.

This annotation is meant for collections. It is meant to be placed on entity members which are collections such as a Set, List, etc.

You should remove this annotation from `student` and replace it with `@OneToOne`

```
public class Data implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int id;
    private String url;
    private String status;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Student student;
}
```

`@OneToOne` means there is one `Student` for every one `Data`
`(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)` means if you save `Data`, its `student` will also be saved.

Another option is to replace the single student with a collection of students.

Comment: The data is not being saved to the table `Student` if I removed `@ElementCollection`. Please update your answer with code how could I do so.

Comment: Sir the what should be the `GenerationType` of the @id in `Student` because I want to make the **ID** of `Data` and `Student` same .?

Comment: One easy way to make sure they are the same is to set the id yourself. Keep `@Id` and remove `@GeneratedValue`, then just set the id member yourself.